# Maintaining packages with different versions in one python environment

Tags: python, version, pytorch, allennlp

I need an older version of torch (0.5.0) for a certain library (allennlp==0.7.2). But I already have an existing torch version (1.0.0) as required by flair and other libraries. How do I cater to different requirements of the same package of multiple libraries in the *same* python environment without having to manually specify the version every time I import that package?

Comment: This was marked as a duplicate but the original question is from 2011!  I think it's reasonable to ask a question again after eight years.